# Need some logic for number game

Tags: javascript, random, numbers

Please visit http://zzzscore.com/1to50/en/ and help me with the logic how the whole cube works. I don't need the code i just need a start how to do this.

Hope sharing link is allowed.

Comment: Link is accessible but the doesn't work/make sense! Please add some more details of what this supposed to do.

Comment: I just want to know how the number cube works...or what language to use...any algorithm or any sort of help..

Answer (score 1):

one approach could be.

1: Create an integer array input with values 1 to 50.

2: for each cell in cube pick a random number from input array and remove this number from array.

3: Whenever use click a cell, fill the cell with one of the random remaining numbers from the input array and pushed it to new output array.

4: When input array becomes empty and user clicked a cell, make the cell content empty. Push the number on the cell to output array and check for the length of output array every time

5: When the new array length becomes 50 stop the game.

Comment: Ty bro...I'll try to work on ur algorithm...Hope for the best